# AMD Firepro W4100 4 monitor issues Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, amd-graphics-card

I have a Windows 10 computer in the office I work. We all have the same computer and the majority of us have 4 monitor setups. The AMD firepro W4100 works perfectly on every other computer on a 4 monitor set up. We all have the same HDMI to mini DP cables. I will say that mine is the only one that has different monitors (2 Acer, 2 Asus, but they are the same size and resolution). On mine, if I restart my computer the 3 other screen will go black and windows will recognize them but not display on them. If I extend to the second monitor it works, I'll see [this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t66OC.jpg)

[image]

---

and when I click the other ones to extend, I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qobfU.jpg).

[image]

---

It is incredibly frustrating.

I can occasionally get it to work, but only if I redownload the amd firepro software, restart the computer, and unplug and replug the monitors (Not always in that order). So I know that the card is capable of making it work, but why does it not always work? Literally any responses would be wonderful.

I can only assume that this has to do with having two different brand monitors as they might have different power requirements? I honestly don't have anything more than guesses.

Comment: Have you tried determining if the issue is limited to your card or your computer? Swap the video card for one that works in someone else's computer. If you still have the problems on your computer the issue is with your computer. If they start having the issues on their computer and you're fine, the issue is with the card.

Answer (score 0):

When running multiple monitors on ATI W series cards using HDMI there are limitations in connectivity.

To allow use of more monitors ensure that active connectors are used if you use passive connectors you are limited to 2 monitors unfortunately.

Refer to ATI manual (although from different graphics it shows idea):
http://www.amd.com/Documents/AMD_FirePro_W600_User_Guide_eng.pdf

In your case it could be also different version of a graphics driver or different length of HDMI cables in between monitors.